# Error with Swift 4 while trying to load image to UIImageView from photos library

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, uiimagepickercontroller

I have been trying to fix an error with importing a picture from the photos app library. I looked into it and found its a `dictionary` key value issue? I am pretty confused any help would be awesome. Code below, as well as error.

```
@IBAction func onClickPickImage(_ sender: Any) {

    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? Any {
        img.image = image
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**error** 'Cannot subscript a value of type `[String : Any]` with an index of type `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey`

Comment: Read apple document first

Comment: Why are you casting the image to `Any` instead of `UIImage`? Do a search and you will found thousands of examples.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
```

For optional binding, use code like this:

```
if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{

}
```

Comment: This may crash. The OP's code is much better (other than the wrong class in the cast).

Answer (score 0):

recently i also worked with photo library, so hope that will help you)

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        img.image = image
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func onClickPickImage(_ sender: Any) {

    let image = UIImagePickerController()

    image.delegate = self

    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image, animated: true){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:-

```
1. UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate 

2. var imagePicker              = UIImagePickerController() (Declare the variable)
3. let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                self.openCamera()
            }))

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                self.openGallary()
            }))

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
   self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

4. // MARK: -
    // MARK: - Image Picker Methods
    func openCamera() {
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func openGallary() {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        NSLog("\(info)")
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage

     }
```